# After new compilation , my custom module's table data was reset in magento 2?

Tags: database, custom, magento2.4.3.p1, db-schema

I have a custom module with the custom table, When i am doing compilation in some time the table data was completely removing and only the empty data base table is exist.

I created this table using db_schema.xml.

Dose anyone faced the same behaviour like this before? Kindly advice on this.

Comment: Never faces this behavior, are you sure you don't have some kinds of underground process in observer updating that table ?

Comment: @Claims not exactly some thing related delete table data.

Comment: It's not possible to without background or any other process. So, try to find out first that thing.

Comment: @RohanHapani true, Will try to find the root cause.